# How are suits filed against federal officials under the First Amendment if there is no implied or express right of action?

Tags: us-constitution, freedom-of-speech, civil-rights

I construe a right of action to be the ability to sue somebody for injunctive and monetary relief.  If there isn't a right of action for the First Amendment like how *Bivens* provided a right of action for the 4th Amendment, how is anybody able to sue a federal official for violating their first amendment rights?

Answer (score 3):

In *Egbert v. Boule*, [596 U.S. ___](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/21pdf/21-147_g31h.pdf) (2022), the Supreme Court held that "there is no *Bivens* action for First Amendment retaliation." The Court was unanimous on this point.

This means that right now, there is no way to sue for a damages remedy for First Amendment retaliation by federal officials. The majority said that "Congress, not the courts, is better suited to authorize such a damages remedy."

Answer (score 1):

Bringing suit for injunctive relief is very likely possible and does not require a *Bivens* remedy, but in the case of a First Amendment violation by a federal government official that is done and over, the First Amendment has become a right without a remedy.